# Progress bar custom image rotate animation

Tags: android

I am trying to use custom image as a progress bar and want to rotate it. I have tried to achieve by one of the answer here but getting error for `<rotate/>` element in the rotate_animation.xml. I understood that the `rotate` element should be in `anim` or `animation` folder but than not getting idea how I can use it in the `rotate_animation.xml` or anywhere so can rotate the progress bar image.

### Error

> Android resource linking failed
>   ../app/src/main/res/drawable/rotate_animation.xml:8: error: resource
>   drawable/load (aka com.example:drawable/load) not found. error: failed
>   linking file resources.

#### Progress bar

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

## Drawables

### rotate_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loader" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loader" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_loader" android:duration="50" />

    <!-- this one is giving error -->
    <rotate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/load"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="330"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:repeatCount="1" />

</animation-list>
```

### progress_indeterminate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rotate_animation"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

Comment: what about `drawable/load` ??

Comment: @Basi oh, I missed to change it. Let me try and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dishu"
        android:duration="50" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dishu"
        android:duration="50" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/dishu"
        android:duration="50" />
    <item android:duration="50">

        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_fav"
            android:fromDegrees="330"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="1"
            android:toDegrees="360" />

    </item>


</animation-list>
```

Comment: Hey Nilesh, thanks but crashing with this error in log `<item> tag requires a 'duration' attribute`